# control custom loggers through glassfish + log4j

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, log4j, slf4j

I have a web app that uses log4j. I have configured a custom logger in the /WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties file like the following :

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CNSL

log4j.appender.CNSL=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CNSL.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CNSL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CNSL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} %p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n


log4j.logger.my.app = INFO
```

The log messages are written to the server.log as expected but am trying to find a way to control the custom logger log levels via the glassfish server.

I tried creating the logger in glassfish from the command :

```
asadmin set-log-level my.app.level=WARNING
```

however all INFO messages are still logged even though the logger is set to WARNING by the asadmin command. Is there a way to control the logger level of the custom loggers configured in the log4j.properties from the glassfish loggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the log level through the console in Glassfish if you use [**`java.util.logging`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) as underlying logging framework in your web application.

You can also use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) in your code and use `java.util.logging` as underlying logging framework (through [slf4j-jdk14.jar](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)).

Comment: I am currently using the SLF4J api with Log4j. Is it as simple placing the slf4j-jdk14.jar somewhere in the classpath?

Comment: Only replace `slf4j-log4j12-version.jar` with `slf4j-jdk14-version.jar`.

Comment: You can't change the level in Glassfish if don't use a **`java.util.logging`** as underlying logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

The asadmin set-log-level command is controlling glassfish logging while you want to control log4j logging. A better alternative would be to have a JMX Mbean so that you can control the log level dynamically at run time. There are [few](https://code.google.com/p/logging-jmx-service/) [links](http://www.sureshpw.com/2012/04/dynamic-logging-with-log4j.html) that could help out.

Comment: So there is no way to control the application logger levels from glassfish loggers?